# What is this attack vector?

Tags: web, csrf, exploit

I've recently started seeing in my log file lots of bad requests that look like this:

http://example.com/somepath/https:/adserver.video/sync/03635d2e5423be5c297a9b6f812b727e/%3Faction=in&uid=9076038541838795658

(`example.com`, here, is MY application domain.)

This is rejected by my ASP.NET application, with the message `A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client` so it isn't causing harm. Yet.

But, even when they don't work, I want to understand the nature of the attack, so I can defend against future versions of it. Here I don't understand what the goal is. The url that they've tried to inject isn't even valid. There's only one slash after the `https` and there's no top level domain (just `adserver.video`). So even if they tricked me or the user to click this, I can't see how it would accomplish anything.

Finally, the server logs show that the referrer is also `example.com`, so I'm wondering if that's faked, or if they're hijacking links on the page and submitting them with script, or waiting for the user to click on them, in which case they're breaking the site, because the links are now poisoned by the bad request. This would be something I need to address.

So, what's going on here, and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an attack, the browser is trying to load a malformed absolute URL as a relative one.

Somewhere on example.com is a link (or video reference, or ajax call) to "https:/adserver.video". Since that URL is badly formed (there's only one `/` after `https:`), the browser is treating it as a relative URL and thus trying to load it from example.com.

Without knowing more about example.com, it looks like it supports ads and an ad with an invalid video URL has been published.

Comment: That sounds about right. The site is my own, but I don't have any of these bad links. I am using a third party streaming video host, but I'm not sure how to identify where they might be messing up.

Comment: Consider hooking up something like Sentry for js error reporting. It should give you more information about what was happening when the url load failed.